# Is it possible to avoid using a JAX-WS provider which gets picked up via service definition in META-INF?

Tags: java, cxf, jax-ws

I'm using the following line to start up a JAX-WS endpoint:

```
Endpoint.publish(url, impl);
```

I have CXF on classpath, so its `Provider` implementation gets picked up by the runtime via `ServiceLoader` mechanism. If I understand the code correctly, the runtime just picks the first `Provider` implementation returned by `ServiceLoader`. As a result, CXF endpoint starts up.

I would like to avoid this. I know that there is a default JAX-WS implementation shipped with JDK (in my case, it's JDK 8). Is it possible to exclude CXF `Provider` or prioritize the default one to be picked up first? (Preferrably without hacks like removing service file definition from CXF jar).

Comment: Note that the newest JDK's do not ship with a default JAX-WS implementation.

Comment: Is it strictly necessary to continue to write `Endpoint.publish`?  Would you be okay with a few lines of code instead of one line?

Comment: @VGR sure, usage of `Endpoint.publish()` is not a requirement. I just want to solve the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to locate the providers yourself:

```
public static Endpoint publish(String address,
                               Object implementor) {

    for (Provider provider : ServiceLoader.load(Provider.class)) {
        if (!provider.getClass().getName().contains("cxf")) {
            return provider.createAndPublishEndpoint(address, implementor);
        }
    }

    throw new RuntimeException(
        "No non-CXF JAW-WS provider found in classpath.");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but in the vanilla case it did not work because CXF was the only provider available via `ServiceProvider`. I also tried to add a different implementation (Metro RT) to the classpath, but it did not work right away, so I reverted to the ugly solution of instantiating the default `Provider` directly. More details in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`Endpoint.publish()` looks for a `Provider` like this:

1. Get an `Iterator` from `ServiceLoader` and take the first element of this iterator
2. **Only** if the `Iterator` is empty, proceed with fallback `Provider` resolution

In my case, there is always something in the iterator, so `Endpoint.publish()` is not an option.

I also tried the solution suggested by @VGR, but it did not work as I had no other `Provider` implementations available to `ServiceProvider` (and the default, the one supplied with the JDK, is **not** available via `ServiceProvider`).

I tried to add a different provider using Metro RT:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>rt</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

But then I got a different problem:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement
```

which was probably caused by the fact that both Metro and old version of CXF were on the classpath.

What worked for me is not very elegant: I just instantiated the default `com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl` directly (using reflection) and added a couple of system properties to work-around issues I stumbled upon:

```
System.setProperty("javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext", "com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory");
Endpoint endpoint =  createWSProvider().createAndPublishEndpoint(url, impl);
```

and

```
private static Provider createWSProvider() {
    final String className = "com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl";

    Class<?> aClass;
    try {
        aClass = Class.forName(className);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    try {
        return (Provider) aClass.getConstructor().newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

1. I used reflection because `com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl` is an internal implementation class and `javac` would refuse to see it.
2. `javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext` is set to work around `java.lang.ClassCastException: blablabla$JaxbAccessorF_bin cannot be cast to com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor`